# Do I need to use firebase functions for my problem?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have the following DB structure:

```
Posts/uid/postID/mediaData...

Timeline/UID/uid:RandID/postRefrence
```

I was going to go with such a DB structure because for the sake of time I wanted to go with a easier to code DB structure that is still able to scale to a good amount of users (max 100) and quickly change it to a more scalable method: only update the users postsNode and then with firebaseFunctions run code in the background which would duplicate the data adding it to all followers.

However, I have come across a problem doing this. What if a user makes a post then someone follows that user, currently I have no code to handle such a situation and thus the new follower would not get any of the posts from the user he followed (added to his timeline which I fetch from).

So it seems that my only option is to have to use fire functions. So that every to observe another node in the DB I have: whoFollowesME. From there I would have to (in the backend) watch for updates and when there is an update I would have to (say someone follows the user) loop through the last x or maybe all posts and add their references to the users timeline.

Question:

**Is this a good approach?** I have never used fire functions so I am not sure how easy it is.

**Should I be considering anything else?**

Comment: If Cloud Functions can do that, so can the client-side code. At least from an SDK perspective, there is fairly little that Cloud Functions can do to the database, that the client can't also do. The choice is typically more based on security concerns.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or searching for a tutorial for web developers. They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have worked with javascript, but i guess there is some unique aspects to fire functions i should learn so i will do that.

Comment: In regards to "If Cloud Functions can do that, so can the client-side code." I had seen a video from firebase about fan out structure and it was said that when the operations scale to large numbers it is better to use firebase functions to achieve the the fan out (by observing the postNode Location), that way the client side does not have to sit forever waiting to update millions of spots in the firebase. This or something similar is what i am wondering if I should do.

Comment: "better to use" is different from "can do it". You can do [fan-out from the client-side SDKs(https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html), or with our Admin SDKs. The main advantage of the latter is that you can run them in an environment of your choosing, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions, so you'll have better control over bandwidth/CPU/memory/etc. But that's unrelated to what they *can* do from an SDK level. If you're familiar with Swift more, I would get started there, just to make it easier on yourself.

Comment: If you know JavaScript already, try to do the fan-out in a faster environment first, such as a local HTML/JS file, StackBlitz/jsbin, or a local Node.js script that you just run with `node fanout.js`. Once you have it working there, you only have to focus on the Cloud Functions bit. That's how I often write my Cloud Functions, and it significantly speeds up my development flow for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Cloud Functions can do that, so can the client-side code. At least from an SDK perspective, there is fairly little that Cloud Functions can do to the database, that the client can't also do. The choice is typically more based on security concerns.

As for you comment on writing many documents from the client: 
"better to use" is different from "can do it". You can do [fan-out from the client-side SDKs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html), or with our Admin SDKs. The main advantage of the latter is that you can run them in an environment of your choosing, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions, so you'll have better control over bandwidth/CPU/memory/etc. But that's unrelated to what they can do from an SDK level. If you're familiar with Swift more, I would get started there, just to make it easier on yourself.

If you know JavaScript already, try to do the fan-out in a faster environment first, such as a local HTML/JS file, StackBlitz/jsbin, or a local Node.js script that you just run with node fanout.js. Once you have it working there, you only have to focus on the Cloud Functions bit. That's how I often write my Cloud Functions, and it significantly speeds up my development flow for them.